# Update Dll Files in TFS and Visual Studio 2010/2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to replace/update a DLL file on TFS server with the same name. But when i CheckIn the Dll it gives below message 
 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is TFS saying the file has not changed: the local copy you are uploading to the server is the same as the one the server already has.

TFS checks with a cryptographic checksum, so the content of the file is used to determine if it has changed.

Comment: No the Dll contents are changed but the name is same. and when i paste it  in TFS it shows CheckOut sign ( red tick ) . but when i try to checkin i get this error. Can we checkIn the DLLs in the same way , we checkin other files???

Comment: @Abdul The checkout happens when TFS detects a file write: there is no consideration of the content of the file. Clearly TFS thinks the file is unchanged. Why not manually generate MD5 (which TFS uses by default: this is file content change detection not security) for old and "new" versions.